# nodejs request address tranlaction

Tags: node.js

I have some link  and  I need that node translate that  to   other link to serve
Like I'm serving some web page but the user cannot see direct address to that link, so node acts like a king of proxy to mask that address and serve that page

Is there any way to do it?

Any help is welcome

Regards

Comment: Yes a kind of that, I need to pipe some address location for a request to a specific link Any recomendation? Regards